# Cross account security group reference in Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Similar to this question:
[How do I add a cloudformation security group ingress rule that refers to another security group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43669106/how-do-i-add-a-cloudformation-security-group-ingress-rule-that-refers-to-another)

Is it possible to reference a security group that lies within another AWS Account?

Ideally I'd like to take a string input parameter like this:
{account-id}/{security-group-id}

This doesn't work, but not sure why not..

```
"SecurityGroupEgress": [
            {
                "Description": "test referencing cross account sg",
                "DestinationSecurityGroupId": "1234455677/sg-124455",
                "IpProtocol": "icmp",
                "FromPort": "-1",
                "ToPort": "-1"
            }
        ],
```

And then reference that within the Template ingress/egress rules.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41736974/aws-security-groups-between-accounts

Comment: I don't think so, but give it a try and tell us what you find!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Pretty sure it doesn't work, but feels like it should be possible. I added an example. Would be a very useful feature I think.

Comment: Would this be for Peered VPCs?

Comment: Peered VPCs, yep, that is our use case atm.

Comment: It looks like it is possible to refer to peered security group ([Updating Your Security Groups to Reference Peer VPC Groups - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/vpc-peering-security-groups.html)), but CloudFormation might not support it.

Comment: Yep, that's right. We currently do it all manually when referencing cross-account/peered resources. Would be great if it was available in cloudformation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this syntax (yaml) to be able to reference a security group from another AWS account:

```
LoadBalancerSecurityGroup
Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
Properties:
  GroupDescription: 'Load Balancer SG'
  VpcId: !Ref VpcId
  SecurityGroupIngress:
  - IpProtocol: tcp
    FromPort: 443
    ToPort: 443
    SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId: '01234567890'
    SourceSecurityGroupId: 'sg-0123456789exampleid'
```

It's an ingress example, for egress, you usually do it the other way around, allowing the access on the other sg (modifying it's ingress).